# SOA Decision Service Error

Tags: oracle, soa, rule

I am receiving a weird error when my SOA system is trying to call a decision service. 
Has anybody seen an error like this before and knows how to get around it?

There are multiple decision services within my application and I read online that this can be a bug within SOA, however, this was working before and then suddenly start giving this error.

If more specific detail is required then please let me know and I can provide it 
 but for now, I am purposely leaving this question without specific details in order to target those who may have encountered this error before.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Is the error intermittent or consistent when calling that decision service? Can you manually call the decision service using the same payload as the faulted caller and check? It could be that a certain combination of inputs or certain data might be causing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this issue was to reload the facts inside my decision service.