# SOA 12c - SOA Folder

Tags: oracle, soa

I have 2 SOA environment - Dev and Test.
For my Dev folder I have the following structure which includes a SOA folder.

[image]

For my test environment, the SOA folder is missing and I don't seem to be able to create it.

[image]

Is this an install issue or can I create this folder?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like soa-infra application on your test environment is not starting properly hence you don't see "SOA" folder in EM. There could be at least a couple dozen reason why it is not working. I would begin analysis by checking your SOA datasource configuration and server startup logs(lok for rows containing "soa-infra").

Comment: Thank you Piotr, that is useful information

Comment: Sorry Piotr, would there by any chance that you could take a look at one of my other questions please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45761748/soa-decision-service-error

Answer (score 1):

Weblogic Console:
[image: Weblogic Console]

---

Yes I agree with Syed the answer, most likely your SOA app is not deployed in the Weblogic console. You may check as per the attached picture.

Answer (score 0):

In your test environment, go to weblogic console/deplpyment and see whether SOA infrastructure is properly deployed and is in active state. Most probably, it is not properly deployed. In such case, please try install it from weblogic console.